# Determine all graphs with size $3n-5$ such that $G-e$ is planar for every edge $e$ of $G$.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I believe I have this one, but I wanted to see if my reasoning is sound since I can only find 1 such graph with this property.

Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$.

First, if $G-e$ is planar for every edge $e \in E(G)$, then $|E(G-e)|=3n-5-1=3n-6$.  Thus, $G-e$ is maximal planar for every edge $e \in E(G)$.  Thus, $\delta (G-e) \ge 3$ $\forall e \in E(G)$.  It follows, that $\delta (G) \ge 3$.  Thus, $G$ has no vertices of degree 2, and so cannot be the subdivision of any graph.  However, $G$ is non-planar, and so must contain a $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ subdivision.  So, our only option is to have $G=K_5$ or $G=K_{3,3}$.  If $G= K_{3,3}$ then $|E(G)|= 9 \ne 3n-5 = 13$.  So, $G\ne K_{3,3}$.  If $G=K_5$, then $|E(G)|=10=3n-5$ while $K_5 -e = K_3 \vee2K_1$ for every edge $e$ of $G$.  Which, by inspection, is maximal planar.

Is my logic sound?  Can anyone find a counter example to this?  Anything that I could be more clear about in my proof?

Comment: $n$ is the number of nodes?

Comment: yes, edited my question to include this.

Comment: There's a gap in your logic here: Since $G$ non-planar it contains a $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ subdivision. But then you say that since $G$ has no vertices of degree 2, it must actually *be* $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$. There are non-planar graphs other than $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ that have no vertices of degree 2, right?

Comment: right...I was misusing a theorem.  The theorem states that no subgraph is a subdivison of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$.  Okay, let me see what I can do to save this.

Comment: Okay, but I can say for sure that every edge of $G$ must be a part of some $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ subdivision.  For otherwise, we could remove that edge and the result would still be non-planar.  Not sure where to go from here, I'll keep thinking.

Comment: I've posted a solution that I believe addresses the concerns raised here in these comments.  If anyone else has a more elegant or clearer solution please post it as an answer and I will likely mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Perry pointed out in the comments, there is a gap in the logic.  There do exist graphs that are not $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ with $\delta (G) \ge 3$ such that $G$ is non-planar.  However, assume that such a graph is given given as a counter example. Then since it is non-planar, it must have some subgraph that has a vertex of degree 2.  Thus, some vertices or edges may be removed to yield a $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ subdivision, but then there is at least one edge, $e_1$ that is not a member of that subdivision, but then $G-e_1$ contains a subdivison of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$, and so is non-planar: a contradiction.